# Error Many to Many Relationship in Laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, relational-database, relationship

I got an error when I try to retrieve many to many relationship data in Laravel. The message of error is

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'id' in where clause is ambiguous (SQL: select * from `jobs` where (not exists (select * from `job_types` inner join `job_types_jobs` on `job_types`.`id` = `job_types_jobs`.`job_types_id` where `jobs`.`id` = `job_types_jobs`.`jobs_id` and `job_types`.`deleted_at` is null) or exists (select * from `job_types` inner join `job_types_jobs` on `job_types`.`id` = `job_types_jobs`.`job_types_id` where `jobs`.`id` = `job_types_jobs`.`jobs_id` and `id` = 3 and `job_types`.`deleted_at` is null) and `name` LIKE %%) and `jobs`.`deleted_at` is null)

**Table**
[image]

**JobTypes.php**

```
public function jobs() // children  
{
    // one type of job has many jobs
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Jobs'); // id refer to jobs.id
}
```

**Jobs.php**

```
public function job_types() // parent 
{
    // one job only belongs to one type of job
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\jobTypes');
}
```

**JobTypeController.php**

```
public function assignJob($id)
{
    $jobType = \App\JobTypes::withTrashed()->find($id);
    $jobs = $jobType->jobs;

    return view('job-types.assign-job', compact(['jobType', 'jobs']));
}
```

**View**

```
<label for="name">Job</label>
                <select selected="selected" multiple class="form-control {{ $errors->first('jobs') ? "is-invalid" : "" }}" name="jobs[]" id="jobs" class="jobs"></select>
                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                    {{ $errors->first('jobs') }}
                </div>
```

**Migarations**

```
Schema::create('job_types', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::create('jobs', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::create('jobs_job_types', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('jobs_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->integer('job_types_id')->unsigned()->index();

        $table->foreign('jobs_id')->references('id')->on('jobs')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('job_types_id')->references('id')->on('job_types')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
```

Comment: Is your `JobTypes` model really called `jobTypes` or `JobTypes`? Change it in `Jobs.php`. In addition, why does the `parent` has a `belongsToMany` relationship - the same as the child?

Comment: it's ```JobTypes```. Parent or child is just description for me.

Comment: But shouldn't it be `belongsToMany` for `Job` -> `JobType` and `hasMany` for `JobType` -> `Job`? This would represent both sides of the relationship. Please try this and check if this solves or changes your problem.

Comment: ``` Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'jobs.job_types_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `jobs` where `jobs`.`job_types_id` = 3 and `jobs`.`job_types_id` is not null and `jobs`.`deleted_at` is null)```

Comment: How is your migration looking like?

Comment: I've updated the code. Please check it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are deviating from the default naming scheme Eloquent uses to identify the fields in the different tables. At the moment, you are using plurals for a column (e.g. `jobs_id`) but Eloquent assumes the singular (´job_id`).

In the `job_job_type` migration file, change all column names and also the schema name to *singular* names. After running `migrate:refresh` (i.e. updating the database schemas), Eloquent will be able to automatically map the relationship to your schema on the database.

```php
Schema::create('job_job_type', function (Blueprint $table) {
  $table->increments('id');
  $table->integer('job_id')->unsigned()->index();
  $table->integer('job_type_id')->unsigned()->index();
    
  $table->foreign('job_id')->references('id')->on('jobs')->onDelete('cascade');
  $table->foreign('job_type_id')->references('id')->on('job_types')->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

Comment: Great! Although nothing wrong with code above. An error because another code... But anyway, thanks!